# How to dynamically add attribute and value to E4X object in Javascript(Compiled on Rhino)?

Tags: rhino, e4x

I want to create an e4x object.
The I want to dynamically keep adding attributes for it and also add value later.
e.g
`var node = <node />;`
//some code
1) add attribute to 'node'
2) add value to 'node'

Also I found such examples for Flex3 but none for Javascript. Any further documentation would also be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add an attribute or value

```
var node = <node/>
node.@id = 123
node.toXMLString()
//returns
//<node id="123"/>
```

if you would like to add attributes named dynamically then use the square brackets

```
node.@["prioritory"] = "high"
//returns
//<node id="123" prioritory="high"/>
```

the same works for adding child elements

```
node.description = "Warning"
node.toXMLString()
//<node id="123" prioritory="high">
//  <description>Warning</description>
//</node>

node["location"] = "R23"
node.toXMLString()
//<node id="123" prioritory="high">
//  <description>Warning</description>
//  <location>R23</location>
//</node>
```

I find this link helpful when trying to refresh my e4x http://wso2.org/project/mashup/0.2/docs/e4xquickstart.html

Comment: If you want to add a node more than once (to create a nodelist), you can do `node += <list-item />`.